# How to install the boost through its source?

Tags: linux, boost

I use the wget download the boost.1.65.1, but I don't know how to install it:

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.65.1/source/boost_1_65_1.tar.gz
```

I have uncompressed it:

```
tar -zxvf boost_1_65_1.tar.gz
```

and I tried to make install it, but failed. Because I cd to `boost_1_65_1` 
then use `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/boost.1.65.1` but says there is no `configure`:

```
[root@localhost boost_1_65_1]# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/boost1.65.1
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

So, how to install the boost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions here: [Boost. Getting Started on Unix Variants.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) You need to setup the builder first and then invoke it if you want to use Boost  not [header-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only) libraries.

Comment: whats mean of `header-only libraries.`?

Comment: @qg_java一坨子给你中疼 Header only  libraries are libraries that consist only of header files (.h or .hpp, often filled with template classes) and do not need to be separately compiled at all. You include them and compile within your own program. Some Boost libraries are header-only. But some are not and you can follow the link in the answer to find out how to build them.